# UILabel sizeToFit crashed when OS version is 11.2 and device's language is Japanese

Tags: objective-c, cjk, sizetofit

I have a simple code as the follow

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
label.text = @"ｱｸｱﾚｱ ｶﾍﾞﾙﾈｿｰｳﾞｨﾆﾖﾝ";
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
```

When I set the device's language to English, it worked normally.

But when I try to set the device's language to Japanese(日本語), it crashed with message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:]: Range {14, 18446744073709551612} out of bounds; string length 19'
```

My OS version is iOS 11.2, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try to add the label to a super view before `call sizeToFit`?

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe this could help you find a solution: adding the label with interface builder and using autolayout the crash doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the line: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f];
Removing this code is working fine and the application is not crashing both the English and Japanese language.